# Is it possible to validate a form without a submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I have normal buttons that I maniulate using jquery for clientside validation. The thing is I would also like to add server side validation but when the input is type submit the jquery code does not work. When I use

```js
$('#addperson').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //code for client side  checks
});
```

The client side code does not work. Please does anybody know if there is a way to have my button work with both client side and server side?

Comment: That's because you are preventing the default behaviour.  If form is invalid prevent default behaviour.

Comment: 1 - click on button; 2 - validate on client side; 3 - either send ajax to server side or redirect to function where you validate on server side

Comment: Please what do you mean by redirect to function ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply first do form validation client side, than do `$('form').submit()` and send all info to server.

```
$('button').click(function () {
     if (validateMyForm()) {
         $('form').submit();
     }
});

function validateMyForm() {
    // check if valid
    [...]

    return isValid
}

<form>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: And what about server side validation? I mean i guess OP is using some ajax (async) to request server and validate data server side **before** submiting `form` or not (like avoiding duplicate user email, etc...). You should use a promise to handle it. Otherwise, if no need to wait for any server side validation, your code is correct of course. EDIT: after i reread question, it is really unclear imho what is expected behaviour, so maybe i'm completly wrong

Comment: what I want is that if a field has been left empty for instance both client side and server side display error messages

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, you are right, if using Ajax and waiting for response, than it's more complicated, but OP does not specify any details about that. So I assume if you use client side validation, than you are not using Ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

'submit event' might help you

```
var valid = false;    
$("#valid").on('change', function(){
  valid = this.checked;
})
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
  console.log(valid);
  if(!valid) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ipt').val('oops, stopped'); 
  } else {
    $('#ipt').val('sending'); 
    //yey
  }
});
```

working jsbin: 
https://jsbin.com/nowirij/4/edit?html,console,output